# Resolve promise conditionally

Tags: javascript, protractor

I'm using the automated testing framework, Protractor.

I've come to find that Protractor frequently makes use of `promises` to asynchronously resolve code evaluation.

Question: How can I manually resolve a promise to a specific value, once a condition is met?

---

Update: 09/08/2017

Sorry, I was just a bit unclear on `promises`. I was able to get this working correctly now with:

```
// match variable
var match = false;

// get all elements with `div` tag
var scanElements = element.all(by.css('div')).each(function(el) {
    // get text content of element
    el.getText().then(function(text) {
        // split words into array based on (space) delimeter
        var sp = text.split(' ');
        for (var i = 0; i < sp.length; i++) {
            if (sp[i] == 'Stack Overflow') {
                match = true;
            }
        }
    });
});

// on complete
scanElements.then(function() {
    if (match) {
        console.log('Status: Found match!');
    }
    else {
        console.log('Status: No match');
    }
});
```

Comment: I've not use protractor, but I've used BlueBird and Q. On those frameworks you have the option to `reject` by `return deferred.reject(data)` the promise and catch the status with a `.fail((data) =>)` handler. Or you can also resolve the promise with different values like `deferred.resolve(myConditionalData1)` ... or `deferred.resolve(myConditionalData2)`. You could resolve the promise on multiple ways, with multiple data values, just need to be handled correctly. Not adding this as response, because I've not worked with the framework you are using. Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

There is no issue here according to the [documentation](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each) the return type of element.all().each() is null after it iterates through everything.

> A promise that will resolve when the function has been called on all the ElementFinders. The promise will resolve to null.

Edit 1:
Is filter a valid option?

```
element.all(by.css('div'))
    .filter(function(element) {
       return element.getText().then(function(text) {
         var sp = text.split(' ');
         for ( var i =0; i< sp.length; i++) {
           if(sp[0] == 'protractor') return true;
         }
         return false;
       });
     }).first();
```

Will first [filter](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.filter) and then return [first](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.first) element that matches

Comment: I guess what I'm looking for is: how do I stop execution of the outer promise, and return the found value once the match is found?

Answer (score 1):

You should use `map` instead of `each`. If you look at the source code, this is how `each` is implemented:

```
each(fn: (elementFinder?: ElementFinder, index?: number) => any): wdpromise.Promise<any> {
  return this.map(fn).then((): any => {
    return null;
  });
}
```

So, as you can see it internally uses `map` and hides the result by returning `null`. It is also pointed out in the [documentation](http://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ElementArrayFinder.prototype.each).

Also rename `element` to something else just to avoid ambiguity with protractor's `element` object.

Answer (score 0):

In your exact example you can use `.getText()` on ElementArrayFinder -

```
// calling .getText() exactly on ElementArrayFinder returns promise
let hasStackOverflow = $$('div').getText().then(texts=> {
    // texts would be array of strings
    return texts.includes('Your Text exact match')
})

hasStackOverflow.then(has=> {
    if (has) {
        console.log('Status: Found match!');
    }
    else {
        console.log('Status: No match');
    }
})
```